# how i delete one node of the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have a problem with my code

```
var carrito = document.querySelector("#carrito");
var noReplace = document.createDocumentFragment();


const añadir1 = () =>{
    text = document.createTextNode(article1);
    li1 = document.createElement("LI");
    let div = document.createElement("DIV");
    let txt = document.createTextNode("BORRAR");
    div.appendChild(txt);
    div.setAttribute("onclick","delete1()");
    noReplace.appendChild(li1);
    li1.appendChild(text);
    li1.appendChild(div);
}
const delete1 = () =>{
    carrito.removeChild(li1);
}
```

if i press 2 times "añadir1" it add 2 li, but, when i wanna delete all these li i got this error
failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

i think if i put an id or a class on the child node that can be deleted, but not is the better idea

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create an `LI`, you overwrite `li1`, so it will always contain the last `LI` that was added. Every delete button will delete this LI, not the LI containing the button. And if you try to delete twice, that `LI` won't exist the second time, so you'll get an error.

Use `addEventListener()` to define the click handler for the delete button. It can then find its parent from the event argument, and delete that LI.

```js
const añadir1 = () => {
  let text = document.createTextNode(article1);
  let li1 = document.createElement("LI");
  let div = document.createElement("DIV");
  let txt = document.createTextNode("BORRAR");
  div.appendChild(txt);
  div.addEventListener("click", delete1);
  noReplace.appendChild(li1);
  li1.appendChild(text);
  li1.appendChild(div);
}

const delete1 = (e) => {
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
}
```